# Formulating the Kruskal-Katona for upper shadows instead of lower shadows

Tags: combinatorics

For $  \mathscr{F}\subset[n]^{(r)}$ we define:

the lower shadow of $ \mathscr{F}$ as $\delta\mathscr{F}$ := {B $\in$ $[n]^{(r-1)} : B \subset A$ for some $A \in \mathscr{F}$}

the upper shadow of $ \mathscr{F}$ as $\delta ^{+}\mathscr{F}$ := {B $\in$ $[n]^{(r+1)} : A \subset B$ for some $A \in \mathscr{F}$}

I have the Kruskal-Katona theorem: Let  $\mathscr{A} \subset [n]^{(k)} $ and let $\mathscr{B}$ be the family consisting of the first $|\mathscr{A}|$ elements of $[n]^{(k)} $ in colex order. Then $|\delta \mathscr{A}| \ge |\delta \mathscr{B}|$

And I want to formulate the corresponding result for the upper shadows. I know it's something to do with taking complements within each layer, and I think the results is meant to be:
 Let  $\mathscr{A} \subset [n]^{(k)} $ and let $\mathscr{B}$ be the family consisting of the first $|\mathscr{A}|$ elements of $[n]^{(k)} $ in lex order. Then $|\delta ^+ \mathscr{A}| \ge |\delta ^+ \mathscr{B}|$, but I can't see any way to get there.

Comment: What is $[n]^{(r)}$? the tuples of length $r$ with coordinates in the set $\{1,2,\dots n\}$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it

Comment: Isn't it similar to the proof of Kruskal-Katona?

Comment: Well I can assume Kruskal-Katona, so I thought there's be an easy way to use it without running though the whole proof?

Answer (score 0):

The Kruskal-Katona theorem for upper shadows can be stated as follows:

**Theorem:**
Let  $\mathcal{F}\subseteq [n]^{(r)}$ and let $\mathcal{A}$ be the family consisting of the final $|\mathcal{F}|$ elements of $[n]^{(r)}$ in colex order. Then $|\partial^+\mathcal{F}|\geq|\partial^+\mathcal{A}|$

**Proof:**

For a family $\mathcal{A}\subseteq [n]^{(r)}$, let $\mathcal{A'}$ be defined as $\mathcal{A'}:=\{[n]\setminus A: A\in \mathcal{A}\}\in[n]^{(n-r)}$

The intuition for why this is the formulation for upper shadows might go along the lines of:

- Taking a shadow of $\mathcal{A'}$ is like taking an upper shadow of $\mathcal{A}$
- Minimising the upper shadow of $\mathcal{A}$ is therefore like minimising the lower shadow of $\mathcal{A'}$
- By Kruskal-Katona for lower shadows, we want to choose $\mathcal{A'}$ to be an initial segment of the colex.
- If $\mathcal{A'}$ is an initial segment of colex of $[n]^{(n-r)}$, then $\mathcal{A}$ is a final segment of colex of $[n]^{(r)}$

Thus the proof is reduced to formalising the intuition above and showing that $\partial(\mathcal{A'})=\partial^+(\mathcal{A})$, and that $A<_{colex}B\iff[n]\setminus B <_{colex} [n]\setminus A$, where $X<_{colex}Y$ means X precedes Y in colex order.